# How to check response in Playwright

Tags: javascript, python, java, webautomation, playwright

I have I question about Playwright. When I make a request to a website with `"page.goto("example_url.com")"` 
Using `page.on("response", lambda res: print(res.status))`
It returns to me more than one response.
My question is how do I deal with this kind of situation to determine if the page has responded to me successfully.

Answer (score 2):

[`page.goto`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page/#page-goto) returns the `Response` of the page where its navigating to. So you can do something like that:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()

    response = page.goto("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/")
    assert response.ok

    browser.close()
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. But in my scenario i have to automate a button click that redirects me to another page so i want to check that response too,  in this way  'response' variable is no longer useful for my second request. Any idea how to do it?